# jquery load with URL as variable and callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, url, callback

I am attempting to to load dynamic content into a DIV using the jquery load function.  I am also only loading fragments of another HTML page.

All works as expected when I pass the URL as a variable or explicitly.  However, when I attempt to pass the URL as a variable and make use of the callback function, things fall apart.

I am hoping it is a matter of incorrect syntax.  My code is below, please help.

Following is the function for loading content into a DIV.

```
function loadContentTest(elementSelector, sourceUrl) {
   $(""+elementSelector+"").load(""+sourceUrl+"",function(){
     $('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox();
   });
}
```

Below this line is an example of the function being called.

```
loadContent('#AboutDiv', 'services_content.html #survey');
```

Comment: *"things fall apart"* Please explain what you mean by that. Explain your problem properly.

Comment: You don't need `""+...+""` around your parameters, although it shouldn't cause a problem.

Comment: What errors is it throwing?

Comment: Well, nothing happens.  The function does not work.  The content is not loaded into the DIV.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

$(""+elementSelector+"").load("'"+sourceUrl+"'",function(){

the double quotes the way you had them aren't doing anything

you say that this works fine , except when you make use of the callback function, the only line in the callback function is

```
$('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox();
```

,try commenting out this line and see if it works.  In the Facebox example they use it on Document ready , try it like they do

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox() 
})
```

Comment: But `'+sourceUrl+'` is not a valid URL.

Comment: @FelixKling fixed - now you can try it

Comment: This will pass `'services_content.html #survey'` which is probably not valid either. Why are you adding `'` to the string? This is incorrect.

Comment: Scott, you are correct.  The Facebox example uses it on Document ready, however I have found that javascript included in loaded content is not executed, so I had to use the facebox function as a callback after the load.

Comment: Felix Kling, do you mean the single quotes around the URL are not valid?

Comment: did you try putting the Facebox stuff in window.onload()  ?  that comes after document.ready

Comment: Scott, I am not sure how I would implement that since I am loading fragments from the URL.  Would I need to place it within each DIV on the page being loaded?

Comment: It appears that removing the ""+ and +"" from the URL variable solved the problem after all.

Comment: ok, updated question to reflect first and second answer, mark as correct if it worked